# Autofac WebAPI Common Service Locator

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac

So reading [Autofac documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#owin-integration) on using it with WebApi, it says:

> A common error in OWIN integration is use of the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration`

I have a `BaseController` which uses the `IMediator` and to get an instance from the container I use the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService()`.

If I don't use `GlobalConfiguration` what other options do I have to inject the `IMediator`.

It's nice not to use constructor injection because then other api controllers don't need to have a constructor, and because of `IMediator` rarely will.

I've looked at property injection but I couldn't understand how to integrate it in the web api scenario, I use the `builder.RegisterApiControllers` and it doesn't look as though integrating property injection on the base controller fits this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`builder.RegisterApiControllers()` returns `IRegistrationBuilder` which means you can continue customizing Controller registration from there.
For instance if you need to apply property injection to your Controllers you could use the following code:

```
builder.RegisterApiControllers().PropertiesAutowired();
```